# How to find the mode of an array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, math, mode

I'm trying to find the mode for my program, a user inputs an amount of numbers from 0-100 as many as they want, I'm attempting to find the mode of these numbers but each time I attempt to find the mode it gives me back a 3, I've found everything else, I just need the help with the mode.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class deveation {
    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int bob[] = new int[101];
        int total = 0;
        int a = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100;
        int mode = 0;
        boolean stay_in_loop = true;

        while (stay_in_loop) {

            System.out.println("Please enter interger(s) from 0-100: ");
            int number = kbReader.nextInt();

            if (number < 0) {
                stay_in_loop = false;
            }

            else {
                total++;
                bob[number]++;
            }
        }

        int median = total / 2 + 1;
        while (median > 0) {
            median -= bob[a];
            a++;
        }
        a--;
        boolean findit = true;
        while (findit) {
            if (bob[min] != 0)
                findit = false;
            else
                min++;
        }

        boolean findme = true;

        while (findme) {
            if (bob[max] != 0)
                findme = false;
            else
                max--;
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < 101; p++) {
            if (bob[p] > mode) {
                mode = bob[p];
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 101; j++)
                if (bob[j] <= mode)
                //I don't know why I'm getting three for this
                {

                }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
            sum += bob[i] * i;

        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println(sum /= total);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(mode);
        //You should start putting down these comments
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. What do you mean by you're always getting three?

Comment: Two answers came in on the same day, but you did not vote, accept or reply - so downvoted. Since a commenter says they cannot reproduce, voting to close as well.

Answer (score 1):

You make `mode = bob[p]`, but `bob[p]` is just how many times the number appeared in your array. The `mode` should really be `p`.

For example, suppose that the `bob` array is:

```
[2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2]
```

This means that `0` appears twice, `1` appears once, `2` appears three times and so on. The `mode` in this case is `2`, which is given by the array index, and not by the value stored in the array.

To find the mode, then, we need to loop through the count array (`bob`), and keep two variables, the `mode` and the highest `count` until now. There is no need to loop twice or use nested loops.

```
int count = 0;
int mode = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < bob.length; p++) {
    // If the count of the p element is greater than the greatest count until now
    if (bob[p] > count) {
        // Update the greatest count
        count = bob[p];
        // p is the new mode
        mode = p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mode is the number(s) that is repeated most often.  I would get rid of the inner for loop that you have.

```
for (int p = 0; p<101; p++) {
    if (bob[p]>mode) {
        mode=bob[p];
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you say you are always getting three.  At the end of the above loop, the mode variable will contain the largest count for a number in your bob array.

You can then loop back through the list (or store the values while looping through it) and print out the numbers that have a count that match your the value of your mode.

```
for (int p = 0; p < 101; p++) {
    if (bob[p] == mode) {
        System.out.println("Mode Number: " + p);
    }
}
```

Remember that mode can be more than one number.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like a hashmap where the key would the number and the value would be the number of occurences. And you can just keep track of the highest value. Also you should be able to do this in O(n) time meaning in one loop through the array. There are plenty of examples online of finding the mode.

Comment: @pbabcdefp ahh yup my bad..missed that